# Ionic Facebook Profile picture showing very small

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework

I am using ionic native facebook for facebook login in my app. All the things are working fine but the issue is when I am getting user data this profile picture of the user is giving too small. When I am getting user data there is photoURL in data but this URL is too small like 30x30. Does anyone know what is the problem or is there another option to get a profile picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by adding this /picture?height=500 in photoUrl
Example : photoUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookUserId + "/picture?height=500"

Answer (score 0):

pass image width and height `picture.width(720).height(720)` 
to `this.fb.api(dataquery, [])`

```
  fbSignup() {
    const dataquery = "me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,picture.width(720).height(720).as(picture_large)";
    this.fb.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then((response: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
      this.fb.api(dataquery, []).then(profile => {
        this.userData = { email: profile['email'], first_name: profile['first_name'], picture: profile['picture_large']['data']['url'], username: profile['name'] }

        console.log("User Data :" + JSON.stringify(response))

      });
    });
  }
```